# SP 2013 Configuration Wizard stuck at step 9 / 10 with SPUpgradeException at SPIisWebSiteWssSequence

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard

I am trying since multiple days installing SharePoint 2013 Foundation farm (no standalone development environment), but the Configuration Wizard stucks doggedly at step 9 of 10. Now I am at the end of my wisdom and my nerves.

Please help me with a solution for this issue. Thank you very much in advance.

## My environment is as follows:

- Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise with IIS version 7.0 (is this IIS version correct?)
- SQL Server Express 2008 R2 ADV (ADV = Advanced Services)
- SharePoint 2013 Foundation with Service Pack 1 and really all possible updates
- My virus protector is off
- My firewall is off

### The Error (in German)

[image: Wizard error message at step 9 of 10]

### in brief:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Action 4.0.3.0 of
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPIisWebSiteWssSequence failed

### The log file says:

> Task upgrade has failed with an unknown exception  Exception:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Action 4.0.3.0 of
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPIisWebSiteWssSequence failed. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine
>   Objektinstanz festgelegt.    bei
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAspSiteMapFile.MergeAspSiteMapFiles(XmlDocument
>   xmldocSiteMap, String strSrcFilePath, String strMergeFilePattern)
>   bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAspSiteMapFile.Copy(String
>   strSrcDir, String strSrcDirPrevious, String strSrcLeaf, String
>   strDestDir, Boolean bMergeMaps, Boolean bBackupExistingFile)    bei
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.CopyAppDomainDirectories(DirectoryInfo
>   vrPath, OverwriteSetting overwrite)    bei
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.Upgrade()    --- Ende
>   der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---

### I tried:

- Deleting cache files and editing cache.ini
- Starting configuration wizard from command line:
- stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
- PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force
- Removing SharePoint and SQL Server and re-install them again

and much more from a hundred of Google findings

BUT NOTHING WORKS!
Please help me with a solution for this issue. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This link may help you. : http://xpertkb.com/upgrade-timer-job-exiting-due-exception-microsoft-sharepoint-upgrade-spiiswebsitewsssequence-failed/

Comment: There are numerous way to start the troubleshooting, and to try the possible fixes. Did you give a shot for `Get-SPProduct -local` as well before running the Configuration Wizard? You could also start the possibly non-running timer jobs by `Start-SPAdminJob -Verbose`.

Comment: I tried the two PS commands and finally it dit not solve the problem, but I could see in the Task Manager that the services SPTimerV4 and as well SPAdminV4 are ended. I tried starting them manually but after some seconds they became ended again!

Regarding the link: I am not able to start the Central Administration and therefore I can not follow the instructions.

Comment: Finally I reformatted my harddisk and reinstalled Windows Server 2008 R2, SQL-Server 2008 and SharePoint 2013. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue, turns out I was missing the web.config file in the virtual directory, which seemed unlikely but sure enough there was no web.config file there, I had to copy it from my other WFE and then we were good to go